# How to scroll to top when screen loads in React Native?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm using `Flatlist` in HomeScreen and it shows me multiple posts. So now what I want is whenever I Signout from the app or close the app and then open the app, I should be able to see the first item from `Flatlist`.

I've tried using `scrollToIndex` inside my render function but it gave me an error - `undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.refs.flatListRef.scrollToIndex')`

```
<FlatList 
    data={this.state.data}
    ref={(ref) => { this.flatListRef = ref; }}
    renderItem={ ({item,index}) =>  this._renderItem(item,index) }
    extraData={[ this.state.data, this.state.checked ]}
/>
```

And this is what I tried using in `componentDidMount` and inside render function `this.refs.flatListRef.scrollToIndex({animated: true,index:0});` but didn't work.

Comment: `this.flatListRef.scrollToIndex({animated: true,index:0})` should fix it, since you're using ref as a callback.

Comment: @PritishVaidya I tried using it inside my render function of Flatlist and it is still not working

Answer (score 1):

*ComponentDidMount* callbacks won't run after the user leaves the app and resumes it later. You have to use [AppState](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate) instead:

> **AppState** can tell you if the app is in the foreground or background, and notify you when the state changes. [[Source]](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate)

Adapt the given example to your needs and scroll with `this.flatListRef.scrollToIndex({animated: true,index:0})}`

Comment: I tried using AppState as used in the Offical React Native document but `AppState`'s  `addEventListener` handler (function) doesn't seems to work. Can you please tell me what's the right way to use AppState?

Answer (score 0):

```
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { useScrollToTop } from '@react-navigation/native';

const ref = React.useRef(null);

useScrollToTop(ref);

const goToTopClickAction = () => {
    ref.current?.scrollTo({
      y: 0,
      animated: true,
    });
  };

// add ref={ref} in ScrollView tag
<ScrollView ref={ref}>
    { ... rest of your code ...}
</ScrollView>
```